# Can a JavaFX property that is bound be modified by CSS?

Tags: css, javafx, property-binding

In JavaFX a property *binding* can often be used to accomplish the same objective as a `ChangeListener` or `InvalidationListener`. Where the property that is affected by the change may need to be set elsewhere, a binding is problematic because a bound property cannot be set (unless binding is bidirectional which has its own set of issues).

With that background I need to know if a property that is bound (e.g. in the skin) can nevertheless be changed by way of CSS in a style file.

I'm working on some controls where I'd like to set the defaults with bindings. If the 'CSS change' is treated the same as setting the value (which won't work) then I'll have to resort to listeners.

Would be grateful for input. Thanks!

Comment: I'd be interested to know what exactly you are trying to accomplish that you need to use listener/binding to set the default values. If it doesn't depend on other control (or something else), then this could have been solved by setting an initial value in the problem, or by calling the corresponding setter during initialization. If it is used for size, then you could have potentially solved it by using the right layout managing `Pane` subclasses.

Comment: @Jai The control is a composite control with a child control that (i) may or may not be visible and (2) has a number of properties whose values depend on whether it (the child) is visible. Because the code that initializes the child is virtually the same as for the 'visible' listener, the initialization for the child is handled by (i) setting the initial 'visible' value to false, (ii) installing the listener, and (iii) setting the 'visible' value to true to trigger the listener when the child is ready to be initialized.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer, no.

A `StyleableProperty` has a corresponding [`CssMetaData`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/css/CssMetaData.html). This latter class has the method [`isSettable(Styleable)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/css/CssMetaData.html#isSettable(S)) which states (**emphasis** mine):

> Check to see if the corresponding property on the given Node is
>   settable. This method is called before any styles are looked up for
>   the given property. It is abstract so that the code can check if the
>   property is settable without expanding the property. **Generally, the
>   property is settable if it is not null or is not bound**.

The existence of this method shows that a `StyleableProperty` has the possibility of being non-settable due to some arbitrary reason.

When implementing your own `StyleableProperty`, and the corresponding `CssMetaData`, you have to implement this method. If the `StyleableProperty` also implements `Property` then this method should check if the `Property` is bound and return `false` if it is. This is what is done for all internal `StyleableProperty`s (that are also a `Property`). Also, if you are using [`StyleablePropertyFactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/css/StyleablePropertyFactory.html) the `CssMetaData` it creates will check if the `StyleableProperty` is an instance of `Property` and then check its bound state.

**Even if `isSettable` returned true this would result in an exception when the CSS engine tries to set the `StyleableProperty`**. As you mention yourself, a bound `Property` cannot be set. And all standard implementations of `Property` will throw an exception if you attempt to do so.

With that said, you have to be careful about how the properties are being set. There is a priority assigned to the method used to set the `StyleableProperty`. The [Javadoc of `StyleableProperty`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/css/StyleableProperty.html) tells you which methods have precedence over the other.

> StyleableProperty allows a javafx.beans.property to be styled from CSS.
>
> This interface allows coordination between CSS processing and a
>   javafx.beans.property. The implementation ensure that the priority for
>   setting the value is, in increasing order and assuming equal
>   importance:
>
> 1. a style from a user agent stylesheet in Application.setUserAgentStylesheet(java.lang.String)
> 2. value set from code, for example calling Node.setOpacity(double)
> 3. a style from an author stylesheet in Scene.getStylesheets() or Parent.getStylesheets()
> 4. a style from Node.setStyle(java.lang.String)

Comment: -Thanks. FWIW I did try to find something like your very good answer, but didn't know where to look. Thanks also for mentioning StyleablePropertyFactory. I use it extensively, but I wonder if I'm in a small minority because every search I've made for examples where it might be used by someone else has always been a dry run.

Comment: @jfr If I'm honest, I've always found JavaFX's documentation regarding CSS somewhat lacking (_especially_ the classes they added in Java 9: `Stylesheet`, `Selector`, etc...). That said, the _JavaFX CSS Reference Guide_ is very useful, I find, for _using_ (not _implementing_) CSS with the standard library. As for `StyleablePropertyFactory`, it was added in Java 8u40 which means a lot of the older examples (mostly based on JavaFX-2) don't show how to use it. I'm also of the opinion that, while it significantly simplifies using `StyleableProperty`s, it suffers from poor design

Comment: Thanks for sharing your views re the CSS documentation. About the `StyleablePropertyFactory` design, it took a lot of trial-and-error before I came up with a pattern that works. Not to complain too much, it was a good learning experience. I have noticed a drawback. If the property being styled is based on a type other than one of the 'canned' options (Paint, Boolean, Enum etc.) then you're left with pre-8u40 solutions or some other workaround. Hasn't been a big problem till now, but would be nice if the factory would be expanded to cover `Object`s.